# SwingUtilities.invokeLater equivalent in WPF

Tags: c#, java, wpf

In WPF UI elements updates' are allowed only on the UI dispatcher thread. Hence, trying to update a UI element from a separate thread will end up in an exception. 
The only way I found on the internet to get around this is to have something like:

```
ThreadStart start = delegate(){
    Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action...
};
new Thread(start).Start();
```

Java has the [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/invokelater.shtml) method to do the same kind of thing.

**My question is:** Is there a specialized WPF utility class with an equivalent of the Java SWING [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/invokelater.shtml)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
   new Action(() => {
      label.Text = "Foo"
   })
);
```

might be more closer to the invokeLater syntax

Comment: Excuse my beginner question, does this run in a separate thread?

Comment: Nope it runs in the same thread as [WPF UI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx)

Comment: Ok, thanks I will give it a try tomorrow and will come back with some feedback :)

Comment: @parapurarajkumar Yes, it runs in the UI thread, but this could be a separate thread (from the current thread). This is the primary reason for the Dispatcher.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the answer is: no there isn't (other than Dispatcher, which I think will help you a lot).

A comment on your code: the threading isn't necessary. Just use

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(...)
```